# Creating Bootstrap Accordionin in a while loop

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a dynamic content field where each data is in a separate accordion and am having a bit of trouble.

Result is the first accordion only works even i am having different id's for each accordion.

Can anyone help me on this

```
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
                            { 
                                $i=1;
                        ?>
                        

<div class="container-fluid border">
                            <table width=100%>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="/images/vehicles/<?php echo strtolower($row['vtype']); ?>.jpg" width="75" heigth="75" alt=""></td>
                                    <td align="center"><b><?php echo $row['vtype']; ?> A/C </b> - <?php echo $row['nos']; ?> Seater<br>
                                    <b>&#8377; <?php if($duration=='8hrs') { $basefare=$row['8hrs']; } elseif($duration=='10hrs') { $basefare=$row['10hrs']; } else { $basefare=$row['12hrs']; } $base=$basefare+($basefare*5/100); echo number_format($base,2,".",","); ?> </b></td>
                                    <td align="right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Book</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div id="accordionfare<?php echo $i; ?>">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" align="right">
                                    <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsefare<?php echo $i; ?>">Fare Details</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapsefare<?php echo $i; ?>" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionfare<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p align="center"><b>Fare Details: </b>Base Fare: &#8377; <?php echo number_format($basefare,2,".",","); ?> | GST @ 5%: &#8377; <?php echo number_format(round($base*5/100),2,".",","); ?> | Extra Hr Fare: &#8377; <?php echo number_format($row['extrahr'],2,".",","); ?>/Hr | Extra Km Fare: &#8377; <?php echo number_format($row['extrakm'],2,".",","); ?>/Km</p>
                                        <?php $i++; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
```

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code. Please show us all of the relevant code.

Comment: what does 'first accordion only works' mean?  First accordion opens and closes?  Only the one accordion element is created?  Do you have any errors in your console log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code replacing your data and it works as expected. Check you PHP error log in case there are errors which might brake the loop in some way.
[Here](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b2se) is a sandbox where you can Execute my test code and check the HTML result

P.S. You must have accordions with different ids in order to open each one separately.

Comment: I didnt find any error in the while loop but i made it by adding foreach instead of while. Now its working. Thanks for suggestion.